# unCaught type error: cannot read property 'null' value for document.getElementByID().value;

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get value of input field but console says cannot read property null value.I have used document.getElementByID().value function. As I do view source the code displays values well but the javascript variable is not getting value. Following is my code:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function addCart(id,name,price)
    {

    var quantity=document.getElementById("quantity_"+id).value;//this line gets error
      
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'addCart.php',
        data:{
          item_id:id,
          item_name:name,
          item_quantity:quantity,
          item_price:price
        },
        success:function(response) {
          document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML=response;
        }
      });
 
    }
 </script>
```

I also tried using jquery get val() function, as follows...

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function addCart(id,name,price)
    {
    var quantity = $('#quantity_'+id).val(); //this line 

    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'addCart.php',
        data:{
          item_id:id,
          item_name:name,
          item_quantity:quantity,
          item_price:price
        },
        success:function(response) {
          document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML=response;
        }
      });
 
    }
 </script>
```

Look my html code:

```html
 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $fetch_customer_menu_result))
      {
        $item_ID=$row['item_id'];
        $item_NAME=$row['item_name'];
        $item_PRICE=$row['item_price'];
       
        echo '          
            <div class="w3-col l8 w3-col s8">
          <input class="form-control w3-left" type="number" placeholder="count" id="quantity_'.$row['item_id'].'" value="1">

              <span class="w3-right"><u>Rate (each):</u></span><br>       
              <span class="w3-right w3-large"><b>Rs. '.$row['item_price'].'</b></span>
                                     
            </div>  
          </div>   
          <div class="w3-col l12 w3-center" style="margin-top: 5px">
            <button type="button" class="w3-red btn form-control" onclick="addCart(\' '.$item_ID.' \',\' '.$item_NAME.' \',\' '.$item_PRICE.' \')" >Add To Cart</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>';
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: Well it is saying getElementById is returning null, so its not finding an element with that id. make sure it exists, and/or that you are passing the correct id value. Probably should show the relevant html, the code that calls addCart, etc

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yess.. I have updated my post.. have a look

Comment: @SamratMunde nowhere in your html/php code does it say "quantity." I think that could be the problem.

Comment: @DivideByZero u cn check the updated one.. ty in advance

Comment: Try: `var quantityString = 'quantity_' + id;` `quantityString 
= quantityString.replace('/\s/g', '');` `var quantity = $(quantityString).val();`

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught type error: cannot read property '`null`' value for `document.getElementById().value;`

This error means that `document.getElementById()` returns a `null` pointer (i.e. it can't find the element that it is looking for, so it returns `null`), and that you are then trying to find the value of a field that doesn't exist (`document.getElementById("quantity_"+id).value` becomes `null.value`, and `null` does not have a field named `value`).

### Why?

The most likely reason (in this case) is that the value you pass in as `id` in your `addCart` function is incorrect. However, there could be a few causes. Follow these debugging steps:

- Make sure that the order of the parameters is the same as defined in your function and where you are calling it (i.e. you are not passing in `name` where you should be passing in `id`)
- Add this line just above the line where you get the error: `console.log("quantity_"+id)` and then use the browser console to check if the text box has **exactly** that ID - if it doesn't, then that is your problem.
- Make sure `addCart` is only being called when the text field is on the screen - ensure you don't delete the text field and then call `addCart`, and that `addCart` doesn't get called before the element has been created.
- Make sure that there are not two functions with the name `addCart`.

Comment: heyy thnx... i tried console.log("quantity_"+id); it shows quantity_ 11 instead of quantity_11... Any solution for this.

Comment: @SamratMunde Find where `addCart` is being called, and find how it is generating the ID variable, and then remove the additional space there.

Comment: as I view source it shows id=quantity_11 but in function on console it gives quantity_ 11...

Comment: Look through your source code in your text editor / IDE, and find `addCart` (do `ctrl+`F` and search for it). Find where it is being called, and see how the ID is being generated there

Comment: hey removing additional space in function worked..thnxx

Comment: it took ID as addCart( 11);

Comment: @SamratMunde Glad I could help! Please don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon to the right of it, so that other people can see what worked to solve this problem in the future